# How to set a value containing a percentage sign in PHPExcel

Tags: formula, phpexcel, percentage

I have been trying to set a value containing a percentage sign in PHPExcel.

I couldn't find how to escape it at all  and all searches point me to how to format a percentage, but that's not what I need.

My current problem is:

```
$cell = 'Z12';
$value = '=Y12-(Y12*20%)';
$excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($cell, $value);
```

Comment: Are you trying to set a string value as `'=Y12-(Y12*20%)'`? To do that, you'd use `$excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValueExcplicit($cell, $value);` Or do you want to use a formula for a calculation? If you don't need to format a calculation result with a `%` sign, please explain exactly what you want.

Comment: @MarkBaker as far as I set a formula the same way I set a value, I want to set the formula "=CV12-(CV12*20%)" as my value so that it can be parsed.

Comment: Well a formula like `=CV12-(CV12*20%)` is perfectly valid as a cell value, and will be parsed as a formula by MS Excel... if you call `getCalculatedValue()` for the cell after setting that value, then PHPExcel will parse and evaluate it as well

Comment: PHPExcel is returning an empty value if the string has a % sign in it.

Comment: It certainly shouldn't: `%` is simply a character in a string like any other, whether that string is a formula or simply a string value.... though in a formula it is also an operator.... are you using `getValue()` or `getCalculatedValue()` in PHPExcel to get it as an empty value, or are you checking in MS Excel? And what is the value in cell Y12?

Comment: The following `$cell = 'Y12';
$value = 100;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($cell, $value);
$cell = 'Z12';
$value = '=Y12-(Y12*20%)';
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($cell, $value);
` gives me a value of `80` in cell `Z12` when I open the saved file in MS Excel

Comment: @MarkBaker It returns an empty cell.

Comment: What returns an empty cell? MS Excel has an empty cell? Y12 is an empty cell? getValue() returns an empty cell? getCalculatedValue() returns an empty cell? I'm trying to understand what your problem is, but completely failing to do so! The code you've posted works perfectly well.

Comment: What is the value in Y12? What is the formula in Z12? (is it still the formula you've posted above?) What format masking (if any) are you applying to Z12? What do you expect to see in Z12?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60106/discussion-between-gilberto-albino-and-mark-baker).

Comment: This problem applies specifically to the Excel5 Writer,it works correctly in other writers. Currently trying to identify a fix, but it seems that none of the alternative Excel writers that I'm familiar with handle the percentage operator either

Comment: Yes. Changing the IOFactory to Excel2007 solved the problem. Anyway, I unfortunately am running PHP 5.2.9 and /Writer/Excel2007/Chart.php file is using PHP 5.4 [] array notation in some methods causing PHP to throw an error. I had this problem solved by manually changing that file. But think, as it is meant to support PHP version 5.2.0 or higher, this should be a problem for backwards compatibility.

Comment: There should be no PHP5.4 notation anywhere in the codebase..... there was, but I thought that I'd reverted it all back again.... if there is still any `[]` array notation, can you let me know exactly whereabouts so that I can fix it

Comment: My current PHPExcel is one month older than last commit. I notice that the current develop branch has it all fixed.

Comment: If you've pulled the develop branch since last night, you'll also have the fix for formulae with the `%` operator in the Excel5 Writer that I'd listed in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is specific to the Excel5 Writer, the percentage operator works correctly in other writers.

I'm about to push a fix to github, but in the meanwhile you can edit the `Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5/Parser.php` file.

Lines 1431-1437 currently read:

```
if($this->_lookahead == '%'){
    $result = $this->_createTree('ptgPercent', $this->_current_token, '');
} else {
    $result = $this->_createTree($this->_current_token, '', '');
}
$this->_advance();
return $result;
```

Modify these with an extra call to `$this->_advance();` for the `%` operator lookahead branch:

```
if($this->_lookahead == '%'){
    $result = $this->_createTree('ptgPercent', $this->_current_token, '');
    $this->_advance();  // Skip the percentage operator once we've pre-built that tree
} else {
    $result = $this->_createTree($this->_current_token, '', '');
}
$this->_advance();
return $result;
```